# Xcode 15 beta 2 - Build Error: "Failed to find or create execution context for description '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x600002588860>'"

Tags: interface-builder, xcode15, ios17

After I've updated to Xcode 15 beta 2, I'm getting these build time errors, which I didn't see in beta 1.

> Failed to find or create execution context for description
> '<IBCocoaTouchPlatformToolDescription: 0x600002588860> System content
> for IBRealityIdiom-seventeenAndLater
> <IBScaleFactorDeviceTypeDescription: 0x600002588b60> scaleFactor=2x,
> renderMode.identifier=(null)'.

I've tried -

- restarting the Xcode15 beta 2,
- re-installing Xcode 15 beta 2 and also, its Commnad Line Tools
- Restarting the macOS (twice)

However, nothing has worked so far. I'd appreciate any suggestions or ideas as to how to fix this issue, because I'm stuck without being able to build the projects.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm also having this issue. I cannot run unit tests because the app won't build for simulators. M1 Mac Ventura 13.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me installing VisionOS runtime resolved the issue. This can be done in Xcode > Settings > Platforms.

[image: Screenshot from Xcode]

Comment: Thanks @atarasenko! That did it for me too!
This is crazy how Xcode beta still always comes with these annoying issues which involve stupid fixes like these which could've been handled by the IDE itself.

Comment: In beta 4 I didn't have the GET button on the Platforms page (possibly a bug as well), so I went back to beta 2 and installed visionOS there. Then it worked in beta 4.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Open your .xib file, select the first property tab, and check the box to turn on "Use Trait Variations".

[image: check the box Use Trait Variations]

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the XIB related deployment target is 7.0 higher, which is very old.
Changing it to 10.0 or higher works.